# I want to deploy my mern stack app on github pages that also uses tailwind css

Tags: deployment, tailwind-css, github-pages, mern

I have built an notes application where you can create your own account and login into it and write, update and delete your own notes. I built this application using React and tailwind css for front end and Nodejs express js and Mongo db for backend. The problem I am facing is that I want to deploy this app on github pages but I am facing some problems.

1. I installed tailwind css in my project using the documentation on their website on the framework's section. My whole application is built I am also able to see results but still my .css files are all empty their is no css writen in it where as I have given classes to the elements and I'm a able to apply it in elements.
2. I don't know how to build this react app for production. I saw some commands on internet like npm run build and it will generate an build folder but what after that?
3. I am using mongo db compass for now and my front end is connecting with backend in using some localhost:5000 call but how can I use this if I want to deploy on the github pages. Also I have some knowledge of mongo db atlas but don't know much about it.

thanks for any help.

if you want full code of this project than it is available on this repository

https://github.com/satanikaushal/inotebook

I tried to deploy my mern stack app on github pages but faced some problems for optimizing it for production.

Comment: Your repository is private; if you want us to check, you must make it public.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know A MERN stack application typically requires a backend server, which cannot be hosted on GitHub Pages. Instead, you can use a cloud provider like Heroku to host the backend server and GitHub Pages to host the frontend.

Building the reactapp for production you would simply use npm run build and it will generate a build folder for you then copy that folder to a github repo